# How do i select datas from two different tables when count() = 2 with join?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a db with 3 tables, as following

```
CREATE TABLE Person
(id_pers number (3),
 name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 phone number (15),
 PRIMARY KEY(id_pers)
);

CREATE table Book(
   id_book number(3),
   title varchar(30),
   about varchar (200),
   nr_of_books number (3),
   type varchar (11),
   PRIMARY KEY(id_book)
);

CREATE table Author(
   id_book number(3),
   id_aut number(3),
   FOREIGN KEY (id_book) REFERENCES Book(id_book),
   FOREIGN KEY (id_aut) REFERENCES Person(id_pers)
);
```

I want to display the title of the book that has exactly 2 authors and the name of the authors which wrote the book. Example "Book1 - Author1, Author2"
All i managed to do is to take the book id and the number of authors but i want them more precisely.

The code that I wrote is this:

```
SELECT au.id_book, count(au.id_aut)
FROM author au join book bk ON au.id_book = bk.id_book 
   JOIN person p ON p.id_pers = au.id_aut 
GROUP BY au.id_book
   HAVING COUNT(au.id_aut) = 2;
```

everything I thought about had as result either "no group by expression" either some error because of the syntax.

Should I make a nested query? if so, what should i type in "where" to be equal to this?
I'm so confused. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: At first glance your query seems fine. I'm not sure what your question is. If you want the title of the book as well, simply add it to the `select`clause AND to the `group by`.

Comment: What error is that query throwing? It seems 100% correct

Comment: I`m not sure it matters for that query,but is it mysql or oracle?

Comment: @MostyMostacho there's no error, but it is incomplete, i want the query to display the name of the book and the name of the authors as well and that's what i don't how to make.

Comment: @Mihai, Oracle. I need a logic at least on how to display the names of the authors so it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will include your title in the result, and it won't give errors about missing group by. I am not sure this is all you want, though...

```
  SELECT au.id_book, bk.title, count(au.id_aut)
    FROM author au 
    JOIN book bk 
      ON au.id_book = bk.id_book 
    JOIN person p 
      ON p.id_pers = au.id_aut 
GROUP BY au.id_book, bk.title
  HAVING COUNT(au.id_aut) = 2;
```

In order to include the authors names, I resorted to something a bit more elaborate:

```
DECLARE @result varchar(500)
DECLARE @numAut int

SET @result = ''
SET @numAut = 2

SELECT @result = @result + [Name] + ', ' 
  FROM person WHERE id_pers in 
      (SELECT id_aut FROM author WHERE id_book in
           (  SELECT id_book FROM author 
            GROUP BY id_book HAVING COUNT(*) = @numAut)
      );

  SELECT bk.title, @result
    FROM author au JOIN book bk ON au.id_book = bk.id_book 
GROUP BY au.id_book, bk.title
  HAVING COUNT(*) = @numAut;
```

First, we enumerate the names of the authors that appear in the "books with N authors"-list. This result Is then included in th (now a bit simpler) actual query, where I basically only select the titles of the books in that same list.

This works, but i am wondering if there is not a more elegant way...

Comment: I want to also display the name of the authors who wrote that book. Any idea how? I was a vague in the description, sorry

Comment: :) So that is why you are joining `person` as well. It does make things a little more complex, wanting data from two records, where up to now we get only one row :) I will sleep on it, as i should be getting some shut eye now. If this is still open tomorrow i will have another look :)

Comment: yeah, i'm on it for two days now but my knowledge stops at this point. Thank you for the help! and have a good night!

Comment: @user2999900, I made a little addition :)

Comment: No wonder i haven't found the solution. I thought there's some simple answer that i miss. Thank you very much for your help:*

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT au.id_book, count(au.id_aut)as count
FROM author au join book bk ON au.id_book = bk.id_book 
   JOIN person p ON p.id_pers = au.id_aut 
GROUP BY au.id_book
   HAVING (count=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your data structure, I don't think the joins are necessary.

Although your query looks fine, the following simpler version may also work:

```
SELECT au.id_book, count(au.id_aut)
FROM author au
GROUP BY au.id_book
HAVING COUNT(au.id_aut) = 2;
```

Comment: well i need the joins because i need to link the id_book(from table author) to the respective title which is in the table book and I also want to display the authors name, that's a connection between author and person. The query should return something like this: "Book1 - Author1, Author 2"

Answer (score 0):

In order to display the book title and the authors you're going to need a [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT au.id_book, bk.title, count(au.id_aut), GROUP_CONCAT(p.name) authors
FROM author au 
JOIN book bk ON au.id_book = bk.id_book 
JOIN person p ON p.id_pers = au.id_aut 
GROUP BY au.id_book, bk.title
HAVING COUNT(au.id_aut) = 2
```

Comment: there's no group_concat in sql developer. Thank you tough